# Keras CNN: Varying Kernel Size

Tags: keras, conv-neural-network

Do you know if it is possible to define a Convolutional Neural Network in Keras so that it can analyze inputs of different lengths? For example, would something like varying kernel_sizes for `tf.keras.layers.Conv1D(filters, kernel_size)` be possible?

Comment: @777It is posisble to vary the kernel_size between the different layers in the network. As for your first question concerning varying the input length, this post should be helpful   https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/388859/is-it-possible-to-give-variable-sized-images-as-input-to-a-convolutional-neural

Comment: Thank you so much @BradleyJuma